# "/Gemfile not found" error is displayed when creating rails application using Rails Composer tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

When I create a new rails application using Rails Composer tool:

```
$ rails new myapp -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb
```

I receive this error:

```
run    bundle install --without production from "."
/Gemfile not found   # <= that is the error
```

That error prevents from finishing building application from template.

Afterwards when I run "bundle install" manually it works fine. I tried to use another rails template (https://github.com/dennybritz/rails_startup_template) and received the same error.

I use Ruby 2.0, rails 4.0.0, rvm 1.23.12

Comment: This smells like a bug. What OS are you using? What options do you select before the bundle attempts to build?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 12.04. The error appears regardless options I selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally resolved. The error refers to the rails-composer issue: https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/issues/138.

I resolved the issue by running "gem update" command in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

"gem update" worked for the same error. "Could not find Gemfile" error.

I received this error cloning a project from a GIT repo.

The confusion started when I can physically see it located in my project directory.

Run gem update definitely helped!